# Tool or service to sweep extract all coins from a private key on multiple L2 chains?

Tags: wallets, addresses, transfer, l2, sweeping

Over the years I have a bunch of accumulated addresses on Ethereum and different L2's (Arbitrum, Matic, BSC, etc...). Currently I want to just consolidate all these dust amounts into a single address. Right now I'm just doing it one at a time, but it would be great if I can just paste my private key somewhere and it would just sweep all coins to another address. I understand pasting private keys on a site is risky, but these are trivial amounts in these addresses and it would be a big time saver if there was a tool or service.